# Can't initialize structure with * void pointer in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have structure:

```
typedef struct node {
  char *question;
  struct node  *no;
  struct node  *yes;
} node;
```

Trying to get memory for structure pointer :

```
node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

And got compile error:

```
 a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "node *"
```

I told visual studio 2012 to compile C code - `Compile as C Code (/TC)`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that for some reason it's still compiling the code as C++ and not C...

Comment: Do the source file name have a `.c` suffix (extension)?

Comment: Are you seeing this problem when you compile? or just in the IDE editor warnings?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `malloc()`'s `void*` to your `node*` is 100% valid C, and your problem is 100% for certain coming from the fact that your compiler is for some reason reading your code as C++ even though you specified `/TC`.

Comment: [In C you *should* not cast `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). It's valid, but you should not do it.

Answer (score -2):

Simply cast the result of malloc.

```
node *n = ( node* )malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Comment: We're not down voting you because we don't like your casting, we're down-voting you because you're completely failing to notice that the poster's actual issue is that he's accidentally compiling in C++ mode.

Comment: @patrick-rutkowski How do you know that? You don't. You are just making assumptions.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The answer to "How do I compile my C code" is not "just rewrite it in C++"...

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant My code is 100% valid C. And perfectly answers the question *How to solve this problem?*